# HTTPError Handling Python3 Firebase DB

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, firebase, firebase-authentication

When I make the authorization call the Firebase with:

```
email = request.POST['email']
password = request.POST['password']
config = {
    "apiKey": "",
    "authDomain": "",
    "databaseURL": "",
    "storageBucket": ""
}
firebase = pyrebase.initialize_app(config)
auth = firebase.auth()
try:
    user = auth.create_user_with_email_and_password(email, password)
    user = auth.refresh(user['refreshToken'])
    request.session['user_uuid'] = user
    if user != "":
        print("You're logged in.")
        return redirect('')
    else:
        print("")

except requests.exceptions.HTTPError as e:
    print(e)
```

I receive this response:

```
"[Errno 400 Client Error: Bad Request for url: 
https://www.googleapis.com/identitytoolkit/v3/relyingparty/signupNewUser?
key=%20AIzaSyCm0XR9oECpQOBTp_iouf3RJTD-Nq0fuXg] {
"error": {
  "errors": [
{
  "domain": "global",
  "reason": "invalid",
  "message": "WEAK_PASSWORD : Password should be at least 6 characters"
 }
],
"code": 400,
"message": "WEAK_PASSWORD : Password should be at least 6 characters"
}
}"
```

I'm trying to parse the message and code from the response, but I keep getting a subscriptable error. I'm using the following code to parse the response:

```
data = e[-1]
data = (json.dumps(json.loads(data), sort_keys = True, indent = 4))
data = json.loads(data)
error = data['error']
error_message = error['message']
print(error_message)
context_dict = {
    'message': error_message
}
```

Comment: You should write and post a [MCVE] that demonstrates the problem. You also seem to have a space encoded at the beginning of the `key` parameter which seems like a mistake

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `pyrebase` raises an updated [`requests.HTTPError` exception](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/#requests.HTTPError); rewrapping the original exception.

You can get to the two values that that exception wraps with the `.args` attribute. It's a tuple with the original exception, and the `request_object.text` value as the second. It is that second value you want to parse, **or** you could use the original exception to get at the response object and use `.json()` to have the requests library do the parsing.

```
except requests.exceptions.HTTPError as e:
    error_json = e.args[1]
    error = json.loads(error_json)['error']
```

or

```
except requests.exceptions.HTTPError as e:
    response = e.args[0].response
    error = response.json()['error']
```

To be honest, I don't quite know why the project does this; the original exception already contains the information they bundle; e.g. instead of re-wrapping the exception, using `original_exception.response.text` produces the same text value.

Comment: Thank you very much. I was very confused and every time I printed "e.response" I got none. Thank you!!

Comment: @Denis: yes, I'm not sure why the project does this, as it masks things needlessly.